# error while redirecting process input from file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm receiving an output error while trying to redirect a process input from a file - reading the file content and writing it to the process input.
the error: `<output file> The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.`

the code:

*before foreach loop:

```
  prc = new Process();
  prc.StartInfo.FileName = prcs;
  prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

*inside foreachloop:

```
  prc = new Process();
  prc.StartInfo.FileName = prcs;
  prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  if (prcs == asProcesses[0])//first process - only redirect output
  {
      prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
      prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      prc.Start();
      sw = prc.StandardInput;
      StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(sInRedirect);
      while ((outputLine = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
           sw.Write(outputLine);
           sw.WriteLine();
      }
      sr = prc.StandardOutput;
      }
```

* i get the message while writing the command: "text1.txt < sort"

- another thing, if i run the program in another computer i get the message:
  " the pipe is being closed"
  thank you for your help!

Comment: What kind of location are you writing the file to?

Comment: That's not what I am asking. What is `sInRedirect`? What kind of location?

Comment: its a text file, but i'm trying to write the content of the text file to the process'input

Comment: This is the third question on this assignment, stackoverflow seems to be really popular in your grade ;-) Read the comments at [Execute Process Chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170273/execute-process-chain) and my answer at [how can i check if the process got output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171945/how-can-i-check-if-the-process-got-output).

Comment: yeah apparently :), though my problem is with reading from a file and not with the piping itself

Comment: Can you use a `try ... catch` to catch the error? If not then it's definitely a problem with Visual Studio and has nothing to do with your program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the permission on your output directory are set in a way that prevents Visual Studio from compiling.
Remove any read-only flags from the project's folder and all subdirectories, clear the output folder and, if necessary, take ownership of the folders or give yourself full permissions.

Source: [msdn - Visual Studio 2010 fails to build or debug reports error 'Failed to write to output file'.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vssetup/thread/20536674-2dc2-4e71-bd6f-4a6a872e009f)

Comment: i read that one as well, i removed the read-only flags and emptied the bin/debug folder, yet it doesn't work