# ReadLine() Callback

Tags: c#, .net, console, readline

When a user types a command into my console, I need to send it to a Java process (Using StreamWriter) that I created. Is there any way to do a ReadLine sort of callback, so when a user types something in the console, I can read it, then pass it to my StreamWriter?

Pseudo Code:

```
private void UserCommand(string text)
{
    if(string.Equals(text, "save"))
    {
        inputWriter.WriteLine("/save-all");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason a loop that calls ReadLine and then UserCommand won't solve your problem?

Comment: you want to do other things while waiting user input?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
UserCommand(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Unlike in GUI programming, console programs are not event-driven. You'll have to call `Console.ReadLine` explicitely which in turns blocks the current thread and waits until the user presses the Enter key. Then you can call your `UserCommand`.

If you want to do other things while waiting for the user's input you'll have to use at least two threads, one which is working and one waiting for `ReadLine` to return (and then calling whatever function you want to call...)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `Console.OpenStandardInput` to get the input stream and use the asynchronous functions of the stream.

```
    static string command = "";
    static System.IO.Stream s;
    static bool quit = false;
    static byte[] buf = new byte[1];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        s = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        s.BeginRead(buf, 0, 1, new AsyncCallback(s_Read), null);
        while (!quit)
        {
            // Do something instead of sleep
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Sleeping");
        }
        s.Close();
    }
    public static void s_Read(IAsyncResult target)
    {
        if (target.IsCompleted)
        {
            int size = s.EndRead(target);
            string input = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
            if (input.EndsWith("\n") || input.EndsWith("\r"))
            {
                if (command.ToLower() == "quit") quit = true;
                Console.Write("Echo: " + command);
                command = "";
            }
            else
                command += input;

            s.BeginRead(buf, 0, 1, new AsyncCallback(s_Read), null);
        }
    }
```